# DocBlock class type inheritance

Tags: php, javadoc, phpdoc, docblocks

Although this question is about [DocBlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) in general, my use-case is about PHP.

Consider the following PHP code:

```
<?php

class ParentClass {
    /**
     * Says 'hi' to the world.
     * @return ParentClass Returns itself for chaining.
     */
    public function say_hi(){
        echo 'hi';
        return $this;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    /**
     * Says 'bye' to the world.
     * @return ChildClass Returns itself for chaining.
     */
    public function say_bye(){
        echo 'bye';
        return $this;
    }
}

$c = new ChildClass;
$c->say_hi()->say_b| <- type hinting won't suggest "say_bye" here

?>
```

This is just a trivial class with some chaining. The extended class looses type hinting because the parent class' docblock is making use of a specific class name which does not have the methods/properties of the child class.

Assuming we do want type-hinting capability, (if not, please leave this question - I don't want useless arguments here), how should I fix this?

I came up with the following possibilities:

- Change the PHPDoc standard to allow a special keyword
- Add a superfluous say_hi() method which calls the parent just to redeclare docblock
- Do not specify the return type at all, let the IDE decide what `return $this;` means (does this even work?)

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this like this :

```
class ParentClass {
    /**
     * Says 'hi' to the world.
     * @return static
     */
    public function say_hi(){
        echo 'hi';
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The "@return static" statement allows exactly what you want, PhpStorm works just fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is commonly called a "fluent interface", where all of an object's methods do their work and return the object itself.

I have not personally seen any PHPDoc guideline finalized on how to do exactly that.  As such, I'm not aware that any IDE has put forth a means for its autocomplete functionality to handle the use case.

A likely path that PHPDoc will take on this is to utilize "@return $this" to be the convention to indicate fluent methods, as it matches the code syntax itself and is therefore very clear.  I doubt that any IDEs will build that capability in until the standard itself incorporates this use case.

In the short term, I think that your superfluous "ChildClass::say_hi(){parent::say_hit();}" *might* get your IDE autocompletion to work.  Again, *might*, because having the autocomplete also recognize method chaining itself (e.g. $foo->bar()->baz()->roll()->tide();) might not exist.

Comment: That seems to work fine with Netbeans, though `@return $this` would be convenient...

Comment: It turns out that phpDocumentor 2.x does recognize "@return self" and "@return $this" to realize the method is a "fluent" method.  In the resulting docs, it highlights "Fluent Interface" methods, and also adjusts the return class type that is displayed on a chlid class doc where it shows the inherited parent method.

Once 2.0.0 stable is officially released, I'd guess that IDEs will implement recognition for this syntax.  Hopefully their autocompletion logic will take the "fluent" recognition and adjust method inheritance correctly.